# Heroku not updated after heroku run:rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

I have a simple blog developed in Rails. When I create a post while in localhost:3000, and then run

```
rake db:migrate
git add .
git commit -m "add blog entry"
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate --trace
```

I get the following output in the command shell:

```
Running rake db:migrate --trace on david-dominique2... up, run.2266

** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
```

Then, when i check mywebsite url, the blog is not updated. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: based on the output, seems no database changes  been made. Did the migration work locally?

Comment: Yes. When I run    rake db:migrate    and I check localhost:3000/articles I see the post I made.

Comment: The post you created locally will not show up on your Heroku site. They use different databases. Correct me if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Please run a `git status` on your project's dir and see if the migration has been committed successfully

Comment: Your git commit message states "add blog entry". It does not sound like you changed the database structure (aka migration). What file(s) has/have been modified to add your blog entry? As @akz92 commented, git status would tell us just that.

Comment: I made a mistake. `git status` will not tell us that. Instead, you can run `git diff --name-only <commit1> <commit2>` where `<commit1>` and `<commit2>` are the starting SHA of your last commit and the commit before that. You can get them by running `git log`

Comment: Justin,  thank you for the clarification.